# I don't understand one chapter on tutorial about pattern matching in F#

Tags: f#

on the following page: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/defining-functions/

there is the following example:

```
type Name = {first:string; last:string} // define a new type
let bob = {first="bob"; last="smith"}   // define a value

// single parameter style
let f1 name =                       // pass in single parameter
   let {first=f; last=l} = name     // extract in body of function
   printfn "first=%s; last=%s" f l
```

I do not understand the line with:

```
let {first=f; last=l} = name
```

I could understand:

```
{f=first; l=last}
```

where it would assign the *first* field to *f* and the *last* field to *l*, but I don't understand the order *first=f*

how does this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question, I think you understand/agree with the way of declaring a record *value*:

```
let bob = {first="bob"; last="smith"}   // define a value
```

OK, let's go!

The left part in a let binding (the `xxx` in `let xxx = yyy`) is really a *pattern*, not a statement nor assignment. You can roughly think a pattern like a regular expression where you can define some placeholders in the pattern.

In common sense, the pattern for a value should be in identical form with the declaration of the value (the `yyy` in the example). Let's write this and you will see why the syntax makes sense:

```
let {first=f; last=l} = {first="bob"; last="smith"}
```

Here, `f` and `l` are placeholders and after this binding, value of `f` will be `"bob"`, value of `l` will be `"smith"`.

> I could understand: `{f=first; l=last}` where it would **assign** the first field to f and the last field to l.

Patterns can be nested, thus your interpretation will become broken when you continue pattern match on `f` and/or `l`. For example:

```
{(Something ff)=first; (Something ll)=last}
```

In short, you should think "assign" here in terms of filling values into placeholders, not the assignment operation (`=`) in traditional languages.

Comment: Ok so if I understood, this is binding a new variable to the pattern matched on the left; is that correct?

Comment: correct, but even more correct if we don't call it a "variable", we should call it a "name", since the term "variable" implies mutable state.

Comment: Yes, understood; I have to get used to that. I did VHDL for a few years and I’m seeing some parallels when it comes to assignments; back then it took me a while to wrap my head around it and it looks like I have to go through something similar with F# :)

Answer (score 4):

The idea is that the syntax is always `{ fieldName = something }`. When you're creating a record, `something` is the value that you're assigning to this field. When you're pattern-matching, `something` is the variable to which you're binding the value of the field.

Comment: To back up your answer, I _think_ the reason that the syntax is always that way, is so that the F# compiler can easily determine what sort of record you are using.  Also, since in F# '=' is more an equivalence operator (i.e. these two things have the same value) rather than an assignment operator, it makes more sense to use = this way as compared to traditional imperative languages.